# jQUery closest span Undefined

Tags: jquery

My jQuery:

```
$(".result").on("click", function(event){
Side;
var Id = $(this).closest('span.bannerid').data('id');
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'someurl/klik?id=' + Id + '&side=' + Side});
});
```

The HTML banner:

```
<div class="result">
<span class="bannerid" data-id="6"></span>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="http://www.sonmeurl" rel="attachment wp-att-42">
<img src="http://www.someimageurl" width="930" height="180">
</a>
</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the ID is undefined for the ajax call it seems like it cannot find the span with the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can get directly with its `class`:

```
var Id = $('span.bannerid').data('id');
```

other more are

```
 var Id = $(this).children('span.bannerid').data('id');
```

and

```
var Id = $(this).find('span.bannerid').data('id');
```

**Note:** `.closest()` will find you the `element at the same level` not the children or grandchildren inside the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

.closest() is for searching a parent or self. Use .find() instead:

```
var Id = $(this).find('span.bannerid').data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a direct child, you can use the `children()` filter. This is ever so slightly more efficient than using `find()`, since it doesn't traverse the whole node - only its direct descendents.

```
$(".result").on("click", function(event) {
    Side;
    var Id = $(this).children('span.bannerid').data('id');
    $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'someurl/klik?id=' + Id + '&side=' + Side});
});
```